# TypeError: unbound method parse() must be called with ElementTree instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to edit an xml file. But on executing the below mentioned code it is showing an error "TypeError: unbound method parse() must be called with ElementTree instance as first argument (got str instance instead)". I have a deadline coming up, Any help will be appreciated

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('lolo.xml')
```

Comment: Try changing your import to `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comment as answer...

Try changing your import to `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`